# localhost returns 404 after adding razor page to the existing web api (ASP.net 6 core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to add razor pages to the project that has my web api's. In my `Views` folder, I have added a `Receiving` folder, then `Index.cshtml` in it. When I compiled the project, it would return 404 error and I have no idea why.

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<OperationsContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IContentRepository, ContentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPackageRepository, PackageRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IShipmentRepository, ShipmentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVendorRepository, VendorRepository>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(c => c.RootDirectory = "/Views"); //adds services for Razor Pages to the app.
var app = builder.Build();


if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI V1");
    });
}
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Shipment}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

app.Run();
```

**Index.csthml**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Receiving";
}

<h2>Shipping System</h2>
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Does anyone know why is it not displaying `Index.cshtml`? Thank you in advance.

I added

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

in `ShipmentController.cs` by the way

Comment: The name of the folder containing views should match the name of the controller. You have two options: Change the controller name to `ReceivingController`. Or, Change the name of the `Receiving` folder to `Shipment`.

Comment: Hi, I did go with the second option and it's still returning 404.

Comment: What is your directory structure like? ProjectName/Views/Shipment/Index.cshtml?

Answer (score 2):

Check the properties for your view and make sure the "Build Action" is not "None".
You can set it "Content".

Comment: It is already set as "Content"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're controller route expects an ID `/{id?}` but your controller action does not have an `id` param.

Comment: Since the `?` mark is added, it is an optional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try browsing the `/Receiving/Index` explicitly? Based on your route configuration, it will return the Index view from the `Shipment` controller. But I think you've not created the `Shipment` controller instead you're using a `Receiving` controller. So either modify the `MapControllerRoute` code to use the `Receiving` controller.

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Receiving}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

or create a shipment controller and view for the Index.

Comment: I just started working with razor yesterday so I may be confused. However, I changed the folder name from **Receiving** to **Shipment** and it's still returning 404 even after entering **localhost:{port}/Shipment/index** as url.

Comment: Did you created a shipment controller?

Comment: Yes, I already wrote everything (and ensured it works) prior to razor pages.

Comment: I changed the folder name to Home and it works. I wonder why?